# Maximize the expression $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$, given that $\frac{1}{x^n}+\frac{1}{y^n}<1$, for natural numbers $x,y,n$

Tags: number-theory

$x$, $y$ are natural numbers such that $\dfrac{1}{x^n}+\dfrac{1}{y^n}<1$. Maximise $\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}$.

Here $n$ is a natural number also.

Comment: Clearly check for $x, y$ among the smallest natural numbers.  Obviously $x, y > 1$ to satisfy the constraint.  If $n=1$ then $(x, y) = (2, 3)$ works to give a maximum of $\dfrac{5}{6}$.  If $n>1$ then $x = y = 2$ gives a maximum of $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using Lagrangian multiplies to find stationary points (saddle points, maxima, minima). As Macavity suggested we gonna split the problem into 2 sub-problems.

**Case 1: $n \geq 2$**

The function is: $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^n} + \frac{1}{y^n} = x^{-n} + y^{-n}$. And we have two constraints those are: $x,y \geq 2$, because otherwise the function will violate the condition $\frac{1}{x^n} + \frac{1}{y^n} < 1$

$$f(x,y) =  x^{-n} + y^{-n}$$
$$g(x) = x \geq 2$$
$$h(y) = y \geq 2$$

$$F(x,y,\lambda,\lambda_1) = x^{-n} + y^{-n} + \lambda(x-2) + \lambda_1(y-2)$$

Now we take partial derivatives:

$$F_x = -nx^{-n-1} + \lambda = 0$$
$$F_y = -ny^{-n-1} + \lambda_1 = 0$$

Beacuse the two last terms has to be equal to zero we have 4 cases.

Cases $\lambda = \lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_1 = 0,x = 2$ and $\lambda = 0, y = 2$ wouldn't work, beacuse that would imply that one of the variables is 0, which isn't possible. That leaves us with only one option: $x = y = 2$

Now checking into the initial function for $(x,y) = (2,2)$ and for a random n, we get that this point is maxima of the function.

So the maximum of the function occurs at $(2,2)$ and it's $f(2,2) = \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$

**Case 2: $n = 1$**

The function now looks like this:

$f(x,y) = x^{-1} + y^{-1}$ and we have constraints the same two constraints and an additional one, which is: $\frac{x+y}{xy} < 1$

$$f(x,y) =  x^{-1} + y^{-1}$$
$$g(x) = x \geq 2$$
$$h(y) = y \geq 2$$
$$j(x,y) = x+y \leq xy - 1$$

$$F(x,y,\lambda,\lambda_1, \lambda_2) = x^{-1} + y^{-1} + \lambda(x-2) + \lambda_1(y-2) + \lambda_2(x+y+1-xy)$$

Now we take partial derivatives:

$$F_x = -x^{-2} + \lambda + \lambda_2 - \lambda_2y = 0$$
$$F_y = -y^{-2} + \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 - \lambda_2x = 0$$

Because the last 3 terms have to be equal to 0, we have 8 distinct cases:

**Sub-case 1: $\lambda = \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$**

This method doesn't give a solution, because it implies $x=y=0$, which is impossible.

**Sub-case 2: $\lambda = \lambda_1 = x+y-xy+1 = 0$**

From $x+y-xy+1 = 0$ we obtain:

$$y+1 = xy-x \implies x(y-1) = y+1 \implies x = \frac{y+1}{y-1}$$

Beacuse x is an integer, this implies $y=2$ and $x=3$.

Also we have:

$$x+1 = xy-y \implies y(x-1) = x+1 \implies y = \frac{x+1}{x-1}$$

Beacuse y is an integer, this implies $x=2$ and $y=3$.

So in this case we obtained two solutions: $$(x,y) = (2,3), (3,2)$$

**Sub-case 3: $\lambda = y-2 = \lambda_2 = 0$**

This implies $(0,2)$ as solution which is imposible.

**Sub-case 4: $\lambda = y-2 = x+y-xy+1 = 0$**

This implies a solution that we've already obtained, which is $(3,2)$.

**Sub-case 5: $x-2 = \lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 0$**

This implies $(2,0)$ as solution which is imposible.

**Sub-case 6: $x-2 = \lambda_1 = x+y-xy+1 = 0$**

This implies a solution that we've already obtained, which is $(2,3)$.

**Sub-case 7: $x-2 = y-2 = \lambda_2 = 0$**

This implies a solution $(2,2)$, which violate the third constrain and is impossible.

**Sub-case 8: $x-2 = y-2 = x+y-xy+1 = 0$**

This is a contradiction, because it's impossible these 3 constraints to be equal to 0.

Because we exhausted all the sub-cases, we check the two solution we obtained and we get that they are global maxima of the function.

**Conclusion**

If $n \geq 2$ then the maximum occurs at point $(2,2)$, otherwise it occurs at points $(3,2)$ and $(2,3)$.

Comment: you can not use lagrange multipliers I think since what I have given you is not a continuous function and cannot be done in this way.But again I have little knowledge about lagrange multipliers so I don't know....please someone tell me if I am correct.I am telling you again to read the question carefully and then answer.Here I have given a discrete case and most probably it can't be solved using usual methods involving calculus.Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know, Lagrange multiplier can be applied to any function to find its stationary points. I double-checked my answer and I didn't find any significant solution. Maybe in the $j(x,y)$ constraint should have been $j(x,y) = xy-x-y-1 \geq 0$, you can try that way, but that won't change much.

This is my opinion, and maybe there is a mistake that I'm not aware of and I hope someone that has a greater knowledge than me will check it and will tell whether I'm wrong or not.

Comment: You could read more about KKT conditions.

Comment: I've tried using Wolfram Alpha and it print the same solution as my calculation.